# How can I read back from a buffer using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I have a third-party library, and I need to use one function in python script from it. Here it is:

```
ReadFromBlob(PVOID blob, INT blob_size, PCSTR section, PCSTR key, const void **buffer, UINT * size)
```

- blob - some pointer? to bytes to read from
- blob_size - blob size in bytes
- section and key - string values like "Image"
- buffer - bytes to read to
- size - buffer size

The documentation gives an example of how to use it:

```
UINT size = 0;
PVOID buffer = NULL;
ReadFromBlob(<blob>, <blob_size>, "MainImage", "Image", &buffer, &size);
```

I'm not familiar with C, so argument types confusing me. I need to be able to read values from the buffer in python.
This is what I have so far:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(path_to_lib)
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
    data = file.read()
blob_size = c_int(len(data))
blob = cast(c_char_p(data), POINTER(c_char * blob_size.value))
b = bytes()
size = c_uint(len(b))
buffer = cast(cast(b, c_void_p), POINTER(c_char * size.value))
lib.ReadFromBlob(blob, blob_size, b"MainImage", b"Image", buffer, pointer(size))
```

But I still get an empty buffer in the end. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have function official documentation? Because the current version is kind of poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the function searches the blob for data based on the section and key and returns a pointer into the blob data and a size, so I made a test function that just echoes back the blob and size as the output parameters:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
void ReadFromBlob(PVOID blob, INT blob_size, PCSTR section, PCSTR key, const void **buffer, UINT * size) {
    printf("section=\"%s\" key=\"%s\"\n",section,key);
    *buffer = blob;            // just echo back input data for example
    *size = (UINT)blob_size;
}
```

The types look like Windows types, and `ctypes` has a submodule `wintypes` with Windows definitions that help get the types right.  Make sure to set the `.argtypes` and `.restype` correctly with parallel `ctypes` types for the Windows types.  This helps `ctypes` check that arguments are passed correctly.

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')

# Note the parallels between C types and ctypes types.
# PVOID is just "pointer to void" and LPVOID mean the same thing, etc.
dll.ReadFromBlob.argtypes = w.LPVOID,w.INT,w.LPCSTR,w.LPCSTR,ct.POINTER(w.LPCVOID),w.LPUINT
dll.ReadFromBlob.restype = None

# storage for returned values, passed by reference as output parameters
buffer = w.LPCVOID()
size = w.UINT()
dll.ReadFromBlob(b'filedata',8,b'Section',b'Key',ct.byref(buffer),ct.byref(size))
print(ct.cast(buffer,ct.c_char_p).value,size.value)
```

Output showing the received section and key, and printing the returned blob data and size:

```
section="Section" key="Key"
b'filedata' 8
```